# extract specific URLs using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract URLs from a lot of text using regex, those URL has specific pattern as follows:

```
http://***/i/***/***
http://***/t/***/***
```

which means any Link with this form:

```
( http://domaine.com/i/text/text )
```

or this form:

```
( http://domaine.com/t/text/text )
```

need to be extracted.

What i did so far is i creating this regular expression :

```
/https?:\/\/(.+?)\/[t|i]\/(.+?)\/(.+)/
```

it is working well till now, but i feel that it is over simplified to be used in production, and it can not be used for this particular situation.

So what i need is another good regex or an improvement of this one in case you see it is not convenient to solve my issue.

Comment: How about `parse_url()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php When you say "extract", what do you mean?

Comment: Why do you consider this expression unsuitable for production? It looks like it satisfies your requirements perfectly.

Comment: If you want alternatives, please provide some detail on exactly what you want to be different - "improvement" is really enough to go on.

Comment: @rickdenhaan its the first time i wrote a regular expression, and it seems to me very simplified. when i check regex of others i see very complexe patterns that i can't even understand. so i i thought it is not good for production.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ok i wil check it. thanks.

Comment: In general, you should always try to simplify an expression as much as possible. Complicated is not always better. This particular expression will probably catch same false positives (try `http://example.com/foo/i/bar/example` for example) but if that's not a problem, go for it.

Comment: A suggestion would be to change (.+?)  to something like: ([^/]+) meaning at least 1 non /   I feel that .+?  is a little broad (but does work) while the one I suggested could be a little more clear/precise.

Comment: @GENE more complex does not mean better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern isn't really bad, you can improve it depending of the context (amount of text in particular, variation of the URL structure you didn't fully describe in your question, other):

first thing: **change the delimiters!**, *this way you avoid to become blind*

```
~https?://(.+?)/[t|i]/(.+?)/(.+)~
```

`[t|i]` means: *a `t` or a `|` or a `i`*, it doesn't means *a `t` or a `i`*; it's a character class, not a group:

```
~https?://(.+?)/[ti]/(.+?)/(.+)~
```

You don't need to capture or group anything, remove the groups if it is the case:

```
~https?://.+?/[ti]/.+?/.+~
```

Non-greedy quantifiers with a dot are slower than a negated character class with a greedy quantifier. Other thing, non-greedy quantifiers with the dot don't prevent to match a slash *(or anything else if the first url of the line doesn't match `/[ti]/[^/]+/.+` and there is another one that does at the end of the line)*:

```
~https?://[^/]+/[ti]/[^/]+/.+~
```

<sup>*(If you are afraid that `[^/]+` matches a newline character, exclude it from the character class: `[^/\n]+`)*</sup>

Better than the last `.+` , you should use `\S+` *(or something more restrictive, perhaps `[^\s?/]+`)*

```
~https?://[^/]+/[ti]/[^/]+/\S+~
```

To finish: sometimes it can be useful to start with a word boundary to ensure that `http` isn't the end of a larger word and because it discards quickly many impossible positions in the string. But, when you do that, keep in mind that a large text contains more word boundaries than `http` substrings. You also need to know that a quick search algorithm is used before the "normal" regex walk to select possible positions in the string when the pattern starts with a literal substring like `http`. If you put a word boundary before this literal substring, this fast algorithm isn't executed. That's why, sometimes when the text is large, a good alternative to:

```
~\bhttps?://[^/]+/[ti]/[^/]+/\S+~
```

can be something like:

```
~http(?<=\bhttp)s?://[^/]+/[ti]/[^/]+/\S+~
```

that checks backward using a lookbehind if the word boundary exists.